# Web Browser is Adding Text to my HTML Link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

So I'm working with this code:

```
<script>
var panel1 = Math.random()
</script>
<a href="//files.explosm.net/rcg/" target=_blank onclick="location.href=this.href+panel1+panel1+panel1+'.png';return false;">Repetitive Comic</a>
```

But whenever I click on "Repetitive Comic" I get sent to a url with the format of "file://files.explosm.net/rcg/*.png" which has an unexpected "files:" in front of it that I don't want. Is this something that my code is doing that I don't know about or is it my browser(Google Chrome)?

Comment: Use a web server to load the page or explicitly write `http://`. `//` means protocol relative, and if the protocol you use to view the page is `file:` then that'll be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be running this as a local HTML file, not accessed over HTTP. So any URL starting with:

```
//
```

...is going to inherit the same "protocol" as your local file, in this case  `file://`.

Prepend `http:` or `https:` if you don't want `file://`

Comment: So I should do <a href="https: //files.explosm.net/rcg/" target=_blank onclick="location.href=this.href+panel1+panel1+panel1+'.png';return false;">Repetitive Comic</a>?

Comment: Yep (without that space after `https:` though)

Comment: Of course, it's just stack overflow reformats it without the space.